# basic bandpass filter

Tags: filters, bandpass

I am attempting to implement a basic bandpass filter but the center frequency of my filter seems to be irrelevant as I can change it all I want but it has no effect on the filter.
where am I going wrong?

I have given my calculations here in the hope that someone will be able to point out where I'm making a mistake.

```
Filter specs:
supression of DC and Fs/2 (zeroes at +1 and -1)
center frequency at pi/4
bandwith of pi/16

2(1-R)=pi/2
1-R=pi/32
R=(pi/32)-1
R=-0.9018252296

 K*(z-1)*(z+1)
---------------
z-R*cos(pi/4)+R

     K*(z^2 -1)
-------------------
z^2-R^2*cos(pi/4)+R

all leading to a difference equation of

Y[n]=R^2*cos(pi/4)*Y[n-1]-R*Y[n-2]+K*(X[n]-X[n-2])
```

Comment: The denominator looks wrong - you need a complex conjugate pole pair.

Comment: the intention is to implement this in c, maybe I should have said that

Comment: I'll be sure to place a similar question in a more appropriate place next time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your denominator is wrong. It should be on this form

$$
(1-z_0z^{-1})(1-z_0^*z^{-1}) = 1-2R\cos(\phi)z^{-1}+R^2z^{-2}
$$
where $z_0 = Re^{j\phi}$.

If your goal is to block DC and create an anti-aliasing filter in a simple way, I would recommend not to use complex poles. Instead use the procedure described in detail here: http://www.dsprelated.com/showmessage/172787/1.php.

It even provides a C implementation.